# Retrieve a widget's scrollController into another widget?

Tags: flutter

In my app a Menu class with a bottom navigation bar is charged to display the different pages of the app through the IndexedStack widget in order to save the state of each page:

menu.dart

```
class Menu extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MenuState createState() => _MenuState();
}

class _MenuState extends State<Menu> {
  final List<Widget> pages = [Home(), Profile()];
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void callbackFunction(int index) {
    setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = index;
    }); 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Save State'),
      ),  

      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _selectedIndex,
        children: pages,
      ),  

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),  
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),  
        ],  
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: (index){
            setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
            });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

home.dart

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  // The item list where the data is stored.
  List<String> items = [];
  // Flags used to check the loading status.
  bool loading = false, allLoaded = false;

  // Function that loads data in the item list.
  mockFetch() async {
    // No more data to load.
    if (allLoaded) {
      return;
    }

    // Set the loading flag to true to prevent this function to be called several times.
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });

    // Simulates the delay that might occurs during an API call.
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));

    // If the item list is higher or equal to 60, an empty array is returned to simulate
    // the end of the data stream. If not, 20 more items are generated. 
    List<String> newData = items.length >= 60 ? [] : List.generate(20, (index) => "List Item ${index + items.length}");

    // Add the new data to the item list.
    if (newData.isNotEmpty) {
      items.addAll(newData);
    }

    // Reset the flags.
    setState(() {
      loading = false;
      // Returns false if the array is empty.
      allLoaded = newData.isEmpty;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Call the mockFetch() function when the state of MyHomePage is initialized for the first time.
    mockFetch();
    // Set a listener.
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels >= _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent && !loading) {
        mockFetch();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        if (items.isNotEmpty) {
          return Stack(
            // Dispay the data.
            children: [
              ListView.separated(
                // Assign the scroll controller to the ListView.
                controller: _scrollController,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  // Display the newly loaded items.
                  if (index < items.length) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(items[index]),
                    );
                  }
                  // An extra item has been added to the index of the list meaning that
                  // all the items have been loaded.
                  else {
                    // Inform the user that there is no more data to load.
                    return Container(
                      width: constraints.maxWidth,
                      height: 50,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text("Nothing more to load"),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
              },
              // Add a separator between each item.
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Divider(height: 1);
              },
              // Add an extra item to the length of the list when all of the items are loaded.
              itemCount: items.length + (allLoaded ? 1 : 0)),

              if (loading)...[
                // Display a progress indicator at the bottom of the list whenever some data is loading.
                Positioned(
                  left: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    width: constraints.maxWidth,
                    height: 80,
                    child: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
                  )
                )
              ]
            ],
          );
        }
        else {
          return Container(
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }

      }
    ),

    ); // Scaffold
  }
}
```

Now the thing is I want my bottom navigation bar to show or hide according to the scrolling direction into the home page.
So I modified the navigation bar in menu.dart:

```
bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedBuilder(
animation: _scrollController,
builder: (context, child) {
  return AnimatedContainer(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    height: _scrollController.hasClients && _scrollController.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse ? 0: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
    child: child,
  );
},

child: SingleChildScrollView(
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
items: [
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
    label: 'Home',
  ),  
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Icon(Icons.person),
    label: 'Profile',
  ),  
],  
currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
    onTap: (index){
        setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = index;
        });
    },
  ),
),
```

),

But of course I need to retrieve the `_scrollController` variable from the home page to get the `AnimatedBuilder` to work.
I've tried different strategies (callback functions, getters...) but none of them have worked so far.

Is there a way to get the `_scrollController` variable from the menu widget or should I consider a different approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Stephan's explanation I managed to set up a way to pass the home page scroll controller.

In the Menu class:

```
class _MenuState extends State<Menu> {
   ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController(); // Initializes a new scroll controller

   void callbackSetScrollController(scrollController) { // Retrieves the Home scroll controller
     setState(()
       _scrollController = scrollController;
     });
   }
```

Replace the page list variable:

```
final List<Widget> pages = [Home(callback: callbackSetScrollControlle), Search(), Profile()];
```

with

```
   body: IndexedStack(
     index: _selectedIndex,
     children: [Home(callback: callbackSetScrollController), Search(), Profile()],
   ),
```

or an error will occur:

> Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'callback'

And finally in the Home class:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
    final Function (ScrollController scrollController) callback;
    Home({ Key? key, required this.callback }) : super(key: key);

   ...

    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      mockFetch();

     _scrollController.addListener(() {
       if (_scrollController.position.pixels >= _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent && !loading) {
         mockFetch();
       }

       widget.callback(_scrollController);  // <= Passes the scroll controller to the Menu widget.
     });
   }

   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a connection from Home back to _MenuState.

What your _MenuState needs to know, could be contained in a variable:

```
bool isNavigationBarVisible = true;
```

In your AnimatedContainer, make the height dependend on that:

```
height: isNavigationBarVisible ? kBottomNavigationBarHeight : 0,
```

Add a callback function to the _MenuState:

```
void callbackNavigationBarVisible(bool visible) {
    setState(() {
        isNavigationBarVisible = visible;
    });
```

Change your Home:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {


Home({Key? key, reuired, required this.callback}) : super(key: key);
      final void Function(bool visible) callback;
    
      @override
      State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
    }
```

When you instantiate Home, hand over the callback:

```
final List<Widget> pages = [Home(callback: callbackNavigationBarVisible), Profile()];
```

In your _HomeState change this:

```
_scrollController.addListener(() {
          if(_scrollController.hasClients && _scrollController.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse){
            widget.callback(false);
          }else{
            widget.callback(true);
          }
          if (_scrollController.position.pixels >= _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent && !loading) {
                mockFetch();
          }
    });
```